# How to prevent file/disk corruption when Linux OS gets shutdown/reset non gracefully?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-device-driver, corruption, corrupt

We have our application running in a Linux VM. Application does lot of read/write with config files in disk along with logging. We often notice when VM gets reset(non-graceful), some of the config files/log files in VM which are in use get corrupted. Are there any file system(we use ext3/4) settings/tuning, fs driver settings we can do to avoid file corruption when a abrupt shutdown/restart happens?

Answer (score 1):

Check this documentation:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt

In summary, you have tree options to mount your partition:

```
data=journal
data=ordered
data=writeback
```

Mounting your partition with "data=journal" option is the safest way of writing data to disk. As you can read in the provided link, with this config option enabled, all data are committed into the journal prior to being written into the main file system.

You can automate that option adding it to your /etc/fstab config file, in the 'options' column.